# Specify order to run testsetup blocks in doctest suite

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

In a big ReStructured Text file with many Python doctests, I have a testsetup block I want to run before each doctest, and some testsetup blocks I want to run before only some of the doctests. I know how to do this with groups, but is there a way to specify in what *order* the testsetup blocks are run?

Here's a file, foo.rst:

```
.. testsetup:: *

  import sys
  sys.stderr.write('testsetup *' + chr(10))

.. testsetup:: my-group

  import sys
  sys.stderr.write('testsetup my-group' + chr(10))

.. doctest:: my-group

  >>> print 'test 1'
  test 1
```

When it's run, I see:

```
testsetup my-group
testsetup *
```

Is there some way to force the opposite order, so the most-widely-applicable setup is run *before* the group-specific setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [latest sphinx source code](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/dfccd80bd247b13c0aac55df134007c186d9c76b/sphinx/ext/doctest.py?at=default) (see `DocTestBuilder.test_doc`), the answer is no, its not possible.  At the moment, all the test blocks are collected in order and either assigned to a group or to a special `add_to_all_groups`.  After this, the code in `add_to_all_groups` is appended to the list of code for each group, the result being that it will always run after group-specific code.  It looks like it would be quite easy to write a patch to change this behaviour, or better still to provide it as an option.